# Поясните работу параметров JavaScript на примере + некоторые вопросы по коду

Tags: javascript, html

Поясните работу параметров JavaScript на примере + правильно ли я понял работу строк кода(указал в комментах)(если что извините за англ)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var row = createRow();
  for (var k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    createElement(row);
    /* ВОПРОС 1: Как используется параметр row (он же функция
     createRow())и каков результат его использования?*/
  };
};
function createRow() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('parent'); // var parent equal <div id = "parent"></div>
  var row = document.createElement('div'); // row = <div></div>
  row.className = "row"; // row = <div class = "row"></div>
  parent.appendChild(row); // adding <div class = "row"></div> after <div id = "parent></div>"
  return row; // now this function equal <div class = "row"></div>
  // and if I'll call createRow() I'll get <div class = "row"></div>
}
function createElement(parent) {/* ВОПРОС 2: parent это параметр.
    Параметр функции это локальная переменная. 
    В последней стоке функции перед параметром вставляется
    <div class = "elem"></div> (он же переменная elem). 
    Но если параметр локальная переменная и в DOM как
    html элемента его нет, то что это вообще такое и где это? 
    Куда тогда вставляется elem ? Как функция работает
    с параметром и куда 
    он девается когда функция сделала с ним все необходимые операции?
    */
  var elem = document.createElement('div'); // var elem equal <div></div>
  elem.className = "elem"; // elem = <div class = "elem"></div>
  parent.appendChild(elem); // adding <div class = "elem"></div> after <div id = "parent"></div>
}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  height: 27px;
}
.elem {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id = "parent"></div>
```

Comment: `row (он же функция
 createRow()` - нет.... он результат выполнения функции...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> row (он же функция  createRow())

нет, `row` - результат выполнения функции. Там же видно, что написано `return row;` - то есть функция возвращает значение. Если бы было написано `var row = createRow;`, тогда да, `row` была бы ссылкой на функцию.

> parent это параметр.
>       Параметр функции это локальная переменная. 
>       В последней стоке функции перед параметром вставляется
>        (он же переменная elem). 
>       Но если параметр локальная переменная и в DOM как
>       html элемента его нет, то что это вообще такое и где это?

`parent`, передаваемый в `createElement()` является объектом.

```
alert( parent instanceof Object ); // true
```

А  объект в JS передается по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

> ВОПРОС 1: Как используется параметр row (он же функция createRow())и
>   каков результат его использования?

`row` - это результат выполнения функции `createRow`. В данном случае это блок `<div class = "row"></div>`, который является дочерним элементом для элемента с id `parent`.

> ВОПРОС 2: parent это параметр.
>       Параметр функции это локальная переменная.  В последней стоке функции перед параметром вставляется  (он же переменная elem).  Но если параметр локальная переменная и в DOM как html элемента его нет, то что это вообще такое и где это? Куда тогда вставляется elem ? Как функция работает с параметром и куда он девается когда функция сделала с ним все необходимые операции?

Это локальная переменная. Но параметром является ссылка на объект, который есть в DOM.

Метод `createElement` создаёт новый `div` и добавляет его к родительскому `div`'у, который был создан в `createRow`, который, в свою очередь, является дочерним элементом `div`'а с id `parent`.

Результатом всего этого будет:

```
<div id = "parent">
   <div class = "row">
      <div class = "elem">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```